# Log row update in GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have asp.net grid view with default update and select columns (they are not converted to template columns)

Now I want to record whenever a user updates a row (i have a column in table: userlog which
can be displayed in the grid view but it is readonly)

I have tried to write my own update statement in GridView_RowUpdated event
but I am not getting the thing done, I wanted to append logged in user id, with
date post stamp, at the end of existing value in userlog column

Please help, currently I am doing the following, in RowUpdated event:

```
string sqlEL = "Select userlog from Schedule Where rowid=" + e.Keys[0].ToString();
        string tmp = dao.GetSingle(sqlEL);
        if (tmp == null || tmp == String.Empty)
            tmp = ".";
        string sqlUp = "Update Schedule set userlog='" + tmp + "' + '"
        + LogthisUser() + "' Where rowid=" + e.Keys[0].ToString();
        dao.UpdateDB(sqlUp);
```

Answer (score 0):

it was due to the fact that readonly column was a simple bound field
and in Asp.Net if you want to limit a column value in edit mode, still showing it
to the user in normal view, then it has to be template field, with `EditItemTemplate`
being removed